# How do I take an image from online and make it pop up as a window when I run it so I can use the image as reference?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

So I am making code that is simulating someone going to a store and buying stuff and they have a random amount of money from a wheel they spin and I want an image of the store layout to pop up on a window so the user can use that for reference when they want to see where they can go to buy things.

I tried to use something called Pillow, which I downloaded in the terminal, but I couldn't get it to work. The file name is called IC-Store-Layout-Loop.png.

[My code for the image to pop up so far]

> from PIL import Image
> Image.open('CSAP CREATE TASK/IC-Store-Layout-Loop.png')

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image.open` opens the image file and returns an image object to you.  It does not DISPLAY anything.  Try this:

```
from PIL import Image
pic = Image.open('CSAP CREATE TASK/IC-Store-Layout-Loop.png')
pic.show()
```